# If I dynamically add a robots meta tag (via JS) will Google and other search engines recognize it?

Tags: javascript, web-crawlers, meta-robots

I want to have a chunk of JS in the middle of my page insert a [`meta`-`robots`](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) element into the `<head>` based on some arbitrary condition.

Will Google and other search engines recognize this tag the same way as if I hardcoded the HTML into the `<head>` section?

Comment: For most search engines no, but for Google that really should be tested since they now try [understand pages by executing JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html). There are some methods for doing that discussed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page) question on SO.

Answer (score 6):

No. Google may sometimes execute Javascript to determine content, but it's a very bad idea to rely on Javascript for your site to be crawled as you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Per these tests by adding robots meta tag will work: https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157 (Adam Audette on May 8, 2015 at 12:32 pm).